# How do I leverage an index with list comprehension?

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I am trying to filter a JSON array based on a value contained in each of the arrays. Provided some user input, I only want to return relevant values based on the type.

Sample json:

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "name": "Golden Shower",
            "type": "Boulder",
            "rating": "V5",
            "stars": 5,
            "starVotes": 131,
            "pitches": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Girls Only",
            "type": "Sport",
            "rating": "5.10a",
            "stars": 4.9,
            "starVotes": 156,
            "pitches": "1"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

I have attempted to use a few variations of a code sample provided on a similar question, but am running in to issues due to slightly more complex data structure. See: [how to filter json array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189892/how-to-filter-json-array-in-python)

I have tried a few variations of code. All of the errors center around improper use of indices. Some things I've tried.

```py
routeData = routesByGpsResp.json()
input_dict = routeData
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['type'] == 'Sport']
```

error: sting indices must be integers

```
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict.items() if ['routes'][x]['type'] == 'Sport']
```

error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I was able to print a list of route names using for statement an index, but cannot seem to figure it out for list comprehension.

```py
for key in range(len(routeData['routes'])):
    print(routeData['routes'][key]['name'])
```

Is list comprehension the wrong way to go here? Should I be using a for statement instead?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `[x for x in routeData['routes'] if x['type'] == 'Sport']`?

Comment: `x` will be `"routes"` in `[x for x in input_dict if x['type'] == 'Sport']`. Thus `x` is an `str`, and ergo the `error`. What you wanted is shown by @cs95

Comment: How's the output data supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: all your attempts are *list comprehensions*, while the variable name suggests a ***dict*** comprehension ([[Python]: PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274)).

Here's an example how you could get *output_dict* (and below, *output_list*) based on your *input_dict*, and the condition(s). As a note: the *dict* comprehension nests a *list* comprehension (which alone constitutes the 2<sup>nd</sup> example) for the *"routes"* key, while for all the other keys leaves the values unchanged:

> ```py
> >>> output_dict = {k: v if k != "routes" else [i for i in v if i["type"] == "Sport"] for k, v in input_dict.items()}
> >>>
> >>> from pprint import pprint
> >>>
> >>> pprint(output_dict)
> {'routes': [{'name': 'Girls Only',
>              'pitches': '1',
>              'rating': '5.10a',
>              'starVotes': 156,
>              'stars': 4.9,
>              'type': 'Sport'}],
>  'success': 1}
> >>>
> >>> # Or if you only want the list
> ...
> >>> output_list = [i for i in input_dict.get("routes", list()) if i["type"] == "Sport"]
> >>>
> >>> pprint(output_list)
> [{'name': 'Girls Only',
>   'pitches': '1',
>   'rating': '5.10a',
>   'starVotes': 156,
>   'stars': 4.9,
>   'type': 'Sport'}]
> ```

Comment: Aaah, didn't think about dict comprehension, a good way to approach the problem too @CristiFati :) +1

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Thank you! Noticed the discrepancy in the question, added a comment asking for more details, and since those didn't come, covered both cases :)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the speedy response and implementation options. I had looked at a dict comprehension, but had trouble wrapping my head around the logic of it. That does indeed provide the output I want. Thanks you for the solution. Now to implement and understand the logic and syntax :)

Comment: You're welcome! I added more details, hope it got easier. Let me know if it didn't to point for more examples (as there are plenty on the internet) :)

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt:

```
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['type'] == 'Sport']
```

`x in input_dict` iterates over the keys, so you are doing `"routes"['type']`, but strings are indexes by integers, and not by a string, 
hence the error `string indices must be integers`

In your second attempt:

```
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict.items() if ['routes'][x]['type'] == 'Sport']
```

`['routes']` is a list, and `x` is a tuple of (`key,value`) obtained by iterating over the dictionary `input_dict`, so `['routes'][x]` raises a `error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

The right way for a list-comprehension, as already pointed out by @cs95, is to iterate over the list of routes by `for x in input_dict.get('routes')`, get the dictionary for the value of key `type` that matches `Sport`

```
print([x for x in input_dict.get('routes') if x.get('type') == 'Sport'])
```

The output is

```
[{'name': 'Girls Only', 'type': 'Sport', 'rating': '5.10a', 'stars': 4.9, 'starVotes': 156, 'pitches': '1'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations behind what is actually going on!

Comment: No worries! Glad to help :)