# how to filter data from url using python on the basis of current date

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, filter

my question is how to extract data on two conditions,

1. todays date,
2. Minimum age limit should be 45 and above

can someone help me to sort this: how to filter the data from given JSON text?

I got the output from the code now I want to find out the center where the availability is there for above 45 age limit and above for today's date. I need to show the whole data of that center

```
    url = 'myurl'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    json_formatted_str = json.dumps(data, indent=2, )
```

output:

```
    {
      "centers": [
        {
          "center_id": 55,
          "name": "abc Hospital GH",
          "sessions": [
            {
              "session_id": "1a",
              "date": "06-05-2021",
              "available_capacity": 0,
              "min_age_limit": 45,
           
              "slots": [
                "09:00AM-11:00AM",
                "11:00AM-01:00PM",
                "01:00PM-03:00PM",
                "03:00PM-06:00PM"
              ]
            },
            {
              "session_id": "2a",
              "date": "07-05-2021",
              "available_capacity": 0,
              "min_age_limit": 45,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "center_id": 638690,
          "name": "xyz Hospital",
          "sessions": [
            {
              "session_id": "2a",
              "date": "06-05-2021",
              "available_capacity": 0,
              "min_age_limit": 45,
            }
          ]
        },
    ]
    }
```

Comment: so the `date` key should be today's date only or any date before today?

Comment: no only current availability i want to see , today's date only

Comment: So for this dict the output should be the first hospital?

Comment: how to put the filter on a given output. there are many hospitals. but i have posted only two here. and the data is dynamic. so for dailly analysis. what will be the code

Comment: Just iterate through the arrays saving them in new ones. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189892/how-to-filter-json-array-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer will also return sessions that dont satisfy your criteria.

Here's a way to omit the sessions that dont match.

```py
def center_check(center):
    center['sessions'] = [sess for sess in center['sessions'] if session_check(sess)]
    if center['sessions']:
        return True
    return False

def session_check(session):
    from datetime import date
    today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    if session['date'] == today and session['min_age_limit'] >= 45:
        return True
    return False

[cent for cent in data['centers'] if center_check(cent)]
```

Comment: Which sessions that don't satisfy the criteria, does my answer return?

Comment: @Sid your `out_lst` contains 2 `sessions`, only 1 should be returned. the dates are 6th may and 7th may, only one of those dates should match

Comment: @yog I have updated my answer, I had thought that you wanted the hospital dictionary.

Comment: sid, exactly, I want the whole hospital dictionary, but when the same hospital included 2 sessions, just show today's session. and not previous

Comment: hey, thanks ranvit, your code gives the exact solution. thank you sid for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

for compairing the data as per your need you need to exctract date and
minimum age limit .
for minimum age limit:

```
minimun_age_limit = json_formatted_str["centers"][1]["min_age_limit"]
```

and for date:

```
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
date_from_response = json_formatted_str["centers"][1]["date"]

if date_from_response.startswith(d1) and minimum_age_limit > 45:
   do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the hospital dict:

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
out_lst = []
for x in a['centers']:
    for session in x['sessions']:
        if session['date'] == today and session['min_age_limit'] == 45:
            out_lst.append(x)
            print(x['center_id']); break
print(out_lst)
```

Here `out_lst` will be a list of all hospital dictionaries matching the criteria.

EDIT if you only want the relevant session:

```py
today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
out_lst = []
for x in a['centers']:
  for session in x['sessions']:
    if session['date'] == today and session['min_age_limit'] == 45:
      out_lst.append(session)
      print(x['center_id']); break
print(out_lst)
```

Comment: hi, sid. I want the whole hospital dictionary, but when the same hospital included 2 sessions, just show today's session. and omit the other session

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using filter():

```
import json
from datetime import date
...
def condition(hospital):
    today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    for session in hospital["sessions"]:
        if (session["date"] == today) and (session["min_age_limit"] >= 45):
            return True
    return False


filtered = filter(condition, data["centers"])
print(json.dumps(list(filtered)))
```

**Edit:**

If you want to omit other sessions you can upgrade the condition method as follows:

```
def condition(hospital):
    today = date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    is_actual = False
    to_delete = []
    for session in hospital["sessions"]:
        if (session["date"] == today) and (session["min_age_limit"] >= 45):
            is_actual = True
        else:
            to_delete.append(session)
            
    for session in to_delete:
        hospital["sessions"].remove(session)
            
    return is_actual
```

This can be a little bit confusing, because the filter method is actually editing the object.

Comment: thank you Levente Simofi, it is working  but I want to omit the sessions other than todays session by keeping hospital data

Comment: okay, I got it, I also edited my answer to fit the problem