# How to get only specific values from YouTube Data API v3 in Python

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I want to create a random video picker in Python, where you input a (YouTube) channel's name, and it picks a random video from this channel. I saw an internet tutorial, which said to use `youtube.channels().list(part="contentDetails",forUsername="GoogleDevelopers")` and then take the playlist ID from this and call `youtube.playlistItems().list(part="snippet",maxResults=50,playlistId="playlistId")`. The problem is: how can I take just the playlist ID from `youtube.channels().list()`, instead of this long thing it normally outputs? This response is stored in a variable and even if there is no way to get just the playlist ID, is there a way to just read the `uploads` value from the variable?

The normal output looks like this:

```
{
    'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse',
    'etag': 'h612UhyviV63eK7y4HMgXE59VnY',
    'pageInfo':
    {
        'totalResults': 1,
        'resultsPerPage': 5
    },
    'items': [
    {
        'kind': 'youtube#channel',
        'etag': 'tjfVDNBL4GkV4fzZBO9NE36KY5o',
        'id': 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw',
        'contentDetails':
        {
            'relatedPlaylists':
            {
                'likes': '',
                'uploads': 'UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Sorry if my English isn't clear and please tell me to provide any further information.

Comment: You can load the response as json and then parse it? It would be somewhat similar to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189892/how-to-filter-json-array-in-python. Not sure if this is the direction you are looking for?

Comment: @DSteman I tested the link in the accepted answer in the question you recommended, where it checks if the string is a valid Json string. It looks like it is not.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` would be your 'normal output':

```
some_variable = x['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
```