# How do I print and filter a Json file in Python

Tags: python, json

code:

```
import json
with open('routes.txt') as routes:
    allRoutes = json.load(routes)

print(allRoutes)
```

Am I doing anything wrong because I get an error and yes `routes.txt` is a file. I would also like to filter it out so I can get a specific value but I can work it out.

my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/-/PycharmProjects/Bots/VA/Cargolux/cargolux_bot/code/rotw.py", line 5, in <module>
    allRoutes = json.load(routes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The file is not valid JSON.  Show the file or at least the first line since that's where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

From your error it looks like the file has some structural problems.
A JSON should have a shape like the example below. Also have a look at [Working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) for further examples.

```json
{
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2",
  "key3": [
    {
      "key4": "value 3",
      "key5": 3,
      "key6": [
        "value 4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "key4": "value 4",
      "key5": 6,
      "key6": [
        "value 5",
        "value 6"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

About filtering have a look at this [How to filter json array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189892/how-to-filter-json-array-in-python). Does it answer your question?